# Binding a nested object with ng-model to a materialize form-component Angular *video included*

Tags: angularjs, materialize

Using materializecss 0.96 and Angular 1.3.15, My form component is now binding to the data in the controller.

You can see from the markup extract below that I'm using ng-model to bind to check.admin.override

```
<label class="section-title">Allow Client Override</label>
<div class="switch right">
    <label>
        Off
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check.admin.override" >
        <span class="lever"></span>
        On
    </label>
</div>
```

The data structure looks like this

```
Client: Object {
    admin: Object,
         number_payments_same: "2"
         override: true
         timeframe: "86400"
    client: Object
    ...
}
```

Not only does the form component not bind (and show the 'on' position) but I am unable to click the component. It won't move!

When I bind the component to a property that is one descendant from the root, I do not experience any problem. For example `ng-model="check.override"`

To illustrate the issue further, [here is a video recording / screencast](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6707713/materialize.mp4)

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried to use a radio component, with no luck. Is this something to do with materializecss?

Comment: your JS snippet here and in the video seems different, we won't be able to help you unless you post working fiddle

Comment: That JS object was crudely copied from the developer console. The pertinent data is as below, thanks. Am building a jsfiddle

Comment: $scope.check = {
        admin: {
            override: false
        },
        client: {}
    };

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a conflict in my code where I'd placed an ng-click on the containing block element meaning it interferes with the switch